# How to dispose database connections when flink retarts

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I use dbcp2.BasicDataSource as database-connection-pool. The database query is used in some map function to get additional info of sensors; I found out that, when the flink job restarts due to exceptions, the old DB connections are still active on the server side.

flink version 1.7

BasicDataSource construct code here

```scala
object DbHelper extends Lazing with Logging {
    private lazy val connectionPool: BasicDataSource = createDataSource()

    private def createDataSource(): BasicDataSource = {
        val conn_str = props.getProperty("db.url")
        val conn_user = props.getProperty("db.user")
        val conn_pwd = props.getProperty("db.pwd")
        val initialSize = props.getProperty("db.initial.size", "3").toInt

        val bds = new BasicDataSource
        bds.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
        bds.setUrl(conn_str)
        bds.setUsername(conn_user)
        bds.setPassword(conn_pwd)
        bds.setInitialSize(initialSize)
        bds
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make sure to close your DB connection when the program terminates. One way of doing this is by adding a shutdown hook (via `sys.addShutdownHook`). Another would be to use `mapPartitions` instead of `map` to limit the number of connections opened, and close them before the method finishes.

Comment: Add close method on sys.addShutdownHook but not work, is there any shutdown hook in Flink.

Answer (score 0):

Change your map function to a `RichMapFunction`. Override the `close()` method of the `RichMapFunction` and put the code to close your database connection there. You should likely be putting the code to open the connection in the `open()` method as well.